# in Traefik, any way to forward request to loadbalancer url subfolder?

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

Is it possible to forward url to subfolder traefik loadbalancer?
like backend server url to http://myserver/myfolder/my

For example:

```
 [http.services.appv2]
    [http.services.appv2.loadBalancer]
      [[http.services.appv2.loadBalancer.servers]]
        url = "http://private-ip-server-2/"
```

Above is normal usage, but I want to do it like: '

```
[http.services.appv2]
    [http.services.appv2.loadBalancer]
      [[http.services.appv2.loadBalancer.servers]]
        url = "http://private-ip-server-2/**mypth/nwepath/path**"
```

i want to to forward my url abc.com to backend https://1.1.1.1/abc-website  and not to https://1.1.1.1/

Comment: usually you append the url

Comment: i did, but it does not work

Comment: already tried, it does not work